# Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory

Tags: trigger.io

I am getting this error (see below)
I have had xcode installed all the time nothing has changed other than updates to trigger, is there something I can do to fix it?

> Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory.
>
> [ !! ] This probably means
> you don't have Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app
> manually and logging output will not be shown!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of iOS are you using on the device? Did it upgrade to 6.1 recently?

The problem is probably that Xcode hasn't yet downloaded what it needs to communicate with the device. If you open Xcode and look at the Organiser, you should see the status light turn green next to the device in the left sidebar.